# Importing some values from hashmap to POJO

Tags: java, jackson, pojo

I want to convert a Hashmap of type  to a POJO. I am using jackson to convert it currently, however, since the request is a API request, the user might provide more fields than needed.
For example,
The hashmap could be :

```
{
  field1ID:"hi",
  field2ID:["HI","HI","JO"],
  field3ID:"bye"
}
```

while the pojo is simply

```
{
  field1ID:"hi",
  field3ID:"bye"
}
```

When using `ObjectMapper.convertValue`, unless there is a one to one mapping from hashmap to pojo, a IllegalArguemetException will be throw. What I wan to do is, if the field is there then map the field. Else leave it as null.

Comment: have you tried to set the object mapper to not fail on unknown properties? i.e. declare the object mapper as such:
`new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)`

Comment: just annotate pojo with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: Take a look at [jackson delay deserializing field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605524/jackson-delay-deserializing-field), [Jackson cannot serialize an my realm object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924580/jackson-cannot-serialize-an-my-realm-object), [Jackson: enum instance methods to return values as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049465/jackson-enum-instance-methods-to-return-values-as-strings).

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any code in your question, consider, for example, you have a map as shown below:

```java
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("firstName", "John");
map.put("lastName", "Doe");
map.put("emails", Arrays.asList("johndoe@mail.com", "john.doe@mail.com"));
map.put("birthday", LocalDate.of(1990, 1, 1));
```

And you want to map it to and instance of `Contact`:

```java
@Data
public class Contact {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<String> emails;
}
```

It could be achieved with the following code:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
Contact contact = mapper.convertValue(map, Contact.class);
```

In the example above, the map has a `birthday` key, which cannot be mapped to any field of the `Contact` class. To prevent the serialization from failing, the [`FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) feature has been disabled.

---

Alternatively, you could annotate the `Contact` class with [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) and set [`ignoreUnknown`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown()) to `true`:

```java
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Contact {
    ...
}
```

And then perform the conversion:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Contact contact = mapper.convertValue(map, Contact.class);
```

---

To convert the `Contact` instance back to a map, you can use:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.convertValue(contact, 
        new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```