# Jackson include a key that is empty string

Tags: java, json, jackson

I accept from a server a json like this:

```
{
  "": "hello"
}
```

And in Jackson I did

```
@JsonProperty("")

private String string
```

When deserialising the object it ignores the property completely.
How can I make an empty string count as a key?

Thank you

Comment: @Jens I would have thought so, too, but I just checked [the grammar](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), and the empty string matches the key for `members`.

Comment: Have you seen this post [How to deserialize empty strings with jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251828/how-to-deserialize-empty-strings-with-jackson)?

Comment: Yes. It talks about enums. I wasn't able to apply to my case... I just want the object to be serialised. Just treat the empty string like any other string. make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to achieve what you want with custom deserializer by following steps.

**Step 1: Create the POJO class you want to deserialize to**

```java
public class MyPojo {
    private String emptyFieldName;

    //constructor, getter, setter and toString
}
```

**Step 2: Create your custom deserializer**

```java
public class MyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyPojo> {
    public MyDeserializer () {
        this(null);
    }

    protected MyDeserializer (Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        String emptyFieldName = jsonNode.get("").asText();

        return new MyPojo(emptyFieldName);
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Register this custom deserializer**

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(MyPojo.class, new MyDeserializer());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);

MyPojo myPojo = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, MyPojo.class);
System.out.println(myPojo.getEmptyFieldName());
```

Console output:

> hello

---

BTW, you could also directly register this custom deserializer on the class:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer.class)
public class MyPojo {
    ...
}
```

For more information, please refer to [Getting Started with Custom Deserialization in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization).